# How can I output the result of a vtkImageReslice into an existing volume without clearing the volume?

Tags: java, python, c++, tcl, vtk

I have several VTK `vtkImageData` volumes that must be combined into a single volume.

Each of the `vtkImageData` volumes should be transformed using `vtkResliceImage` before being placed into the resulting volume.

Currently, each `vtkImageData` is rotated into a new `vtkImageData` using `vtkResliceImage` and all rotated volumes are combined using `vtkImageMathematics`. This process is slooow.

For all volumes, I would like the output of `vtkResliceImage` to go into the same `vtkImageData`. It's no problem if parts of the `vtkImageData` are overwritten.

How can I tell VTK not to reinitialize the output `vtkImageData`? I tried setting the output using `SetOutput` but that's not sufficient.

An answer in any programming language with bindings to VTK is welcome.

Comment: can you apply the vtkImageMathematics to the original images and then rotate the result? This will reduce the ammount of calls to the vtkReslice fairly

Comment: Unfortunately not because the images all have different orientations.